# Azure Website adding subdomain

Tags: c#, azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

Is there a part of the Azure SDK which gives programmatic access to Creating a CNAME for a website and binding it to an SSL certificate?

We have a multi-tenant app and we want to be able to programatically add the CNAME and binding records for customers as they sign up rather than manually adding them through the portal. Effectively replicating the functionality available in the "Custom Domains and SSL" blade of a website in the new Portal

e.g. our site is examplesitename.com and we want to be able to add
customer1.examplesitename.com and bind to SSL so its accessibly as https://customer1.examplesitename.com.

(Our application manages the tenancy internally based on the subdomain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example Management project [Repo](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/tree/master/ManagementLibrarySample) By David Ebbo, demonstrates some of the functionality using the new ARM Libraries

There are several hoops which need jumping through. This PR also includes a working example for binding to Azure DNS [enter link description here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/pull/5)